# how to install another version of boost on xubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, repository, apt-get

I'm trying to compile https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero and it specifically tells to install boost 1.53 or higher, but not 1.54. From that prerequisite it follows immediately that when I install libboost-all-dev, it installs version 1.54. How to proceed next? I tried this, but as you can see from the last line it doesn't work. Why doesn't that work?

```
vagrant@vagrant-eclipse:~$ rmadison libboost-all-dev
 libboost-all-dev | 1.48.0.2        | precise/universe | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libboost-all-dev | 1.54.0.1ubuntu1 | trusty/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libboost-all-dev | 1.55.0.2        | vivid/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libboost-all-dev | 1.58.0.0ubuntu1 | wily/universe    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libboost-all-dev | 1.58.0.1        | xenial/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
vagrant@vagrant-eclipse:~$ sudo apt-add-repository http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/wily/universe
vagrant@vagrant-eclipse:~$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev=1.58.0.0ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.58.0.0ubuntu1' for 'libboost-all-dev' was not found
```

Comment: I found a workaround by downloading the right package from the bottom of https://packages.debian.org/sid/libboost-all-dev ,  then doubleclicking the file and click "upgrade".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can remove libboost-all-dev without breaking your whole universe (a tricky thing) then you can

```
apt-get install libboost1.55-all-dev
```

as 1.55 has been (mis-)packaged for trusty in the canonical repositories.